# Filter Repeating Character Strings

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function (in JS) that takes an array as an argument and returns new array by filtering it (argument) and leaving elements with repetitive characters.

```
identicalFilter(["aaaaaa", "bc", "d", "eeee", "xyz"]) // => ["aaaaaa", "d", "eeee"]
identicalFilter(["88", "999", "22", "5454", "31333"]) // => ["88", "999", "22"]
```

So far, I've come up with this code and really screwed up

```
function identicalFilter(arr) {
    let newArr = [];
    let tempArr = arr.forEach(key => {
        return key.split('');
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < tempArr.length; i++){
        let count = 0;
        for (let k = 0; k < tempArr[i].length; k++){
            if (tempArr[i][0]===tempArr[i][i]) {
                count++;
            }
            if (count === temArr[i].length){
                newArr.push(tempArr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

SOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` & `every`. Inside the `reduce` callback get the first character and then use `every` to check if all elements are same

```js
function identicalFilter(arr) {
  if (arr.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }
  return arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let firstChar = curr.charAt(0);
    let isSame = curr.split('').every(item => item === firstChar);
    if (isSame) {
      acc.push(curr)
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
}





console.log(identicalFilter(["aaaaaa", "bc", "d", "eeee", "xyz"]))
console.log(identicalFilter(["88", "999", "22", "5454", "31333"]))
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

How about using a regular expression instead? Match and capture the first character, then backreference that character as many times as needed until reaching the end of the string:

```js
const identicalFilter = arr => arr.filter(
  str => /^(.)\1*$/.test(str)
);

console.log(identicalFilter(["aaaaaa", "bc", "d", "eeee", "xyz"])) // => ["aaaaaa", "d", "eeee"]
console.log(identicalFilter(["88", "999", "22", "5454", "31333"])) // => ["88", "999", "22"]
```

If you don't like regular expressions, you could also turn the string into an array and check that `.every` one of its characters is the same as the first:

```js
const identicalFilter = arr => arr.filter((str) => {
  const arr = [...str];
  const firstChar = arr.shift();
  return arr.every(char => char === firstChar);
});

console.log(identicalFilter(["aaaaaa", "bc", "d", "eeee", "xyz"])) // => ["aaaaaa", "d", "eeee"]
console.log(identicalFilter(["88", "999", "22", "5454", "31333"])) // => ["88", "999", "22"]
```

Comment: Hey, the second snippet worked well. But somehow, the first snippet returned undefined. I'm not very good at regex, so can you explain more in detail how your wrote regex, please?

Comment: The first snippet produces the desired results - you can press "Run code snippet" to see it working. It cannot return `undefined` - `.filter` *must* return an array, and `.test` *must* return `true` or `false`. If you get `undefined`, it sounds like you didn't copy the code exactly

Comment: The pattern is really simple. Like I said: *Match and capture the first character, then backreference that character as many times as needed until reaching the end of the string*. The `(.)` captures the first character, and then the `\1*` backreferences it as many times as needed.

Comment: Yeah, i think I've omitted something while copying the snippet. Both snippets worked awesome! I appreciate it!